# MS Graph API 403 error when calling users even access is granted

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am generating access token by the following route in my node.js

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

After that I get access_token but no scope parameter.

When i try to hit the [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(givenName,'J')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(givenName,%27J%27))
url with Authorization Header added i get

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-05-13T18:10:19",
            "request-id": "7086d829-13c1-4671-8bd4-9f365aa29417",
            "client-request-id": "7086d829-13c1-4671-8bd4-9f365aa29417"
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I have granted permissions and admin consent.

I would really appreciate any help.

PS(I have owner access to the app and AAD)

Comment: And which permissions have you granted to your app?

Comment: I have granted the 

Policy.ReadWrite.DeviceConfiguration
Policy.ReadWrite.FeatureRollout
Policy.ReadWrite.MobilityManagement
Policy.ReadWrite.PermissionGrant
Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework
profile
RoleAssignmentSchedule.Read.Directory
RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory
SearchConfiguration.Read.All
SearchConfiguration.ReadWrite.All
TeamMember.Read.All
TeamMember.ReadWrite.All
TeamMember.ReadWriteNonOwnerRole.All
User.Export.All
User.Invite.All
User.ManageIdentities.All
User.Read
User.Read.All
User.ReadBasic.All
User.ReadWrite
User.ReadWrite.All

Comment: AccessReview.Read.All
AccessReview.ReadWrite.All
AccessReview.ReadWrite.Membership
AdministrativeUnit.Read.All
AdministrativeUnit.ReadWrite.All
Directory.AccessAsUser.All
Directory.Read.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
Directory.Write.Restricted
DirectoryRecommendations.Read.All
DirectoryRecommendations.ReadWrite.All
email
offline_access
openid
Policy.Read.All
Policy.Read.ConditionalAccess
Policy.Read.PermissionGrant
Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration
Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationFlows
Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationMethod

Comment: Policy.ReadWrite.Authorization
Policy.ReadWrite.ConditionalAccess
Policy.ReadWrite.ConsentRequest
Policy.ReadWrite.CrossTenantAccess

Comment: Check the doc which permissions are required for /users endpoint.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Answer (score 0):

I can successfully call the users endpoint from your example with an app registration that only has the **User.Read.All** permission. One thing that may be wrong in your app registration is the permissiontype for User.Read.All. It should be either **Application** or **Delegated**. With the incorrect permissiontype I get the exact same error response.

If you get your accesstoken with a user login it should be **Delegated**, otherwise **Application**.

[image: Screenshot for a bit of context]

I investigated a similar issue using Postman and the MS Graph Postman collection. It's really nice for some quick trial and error. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman for guidance. Make sure to get a new token every time you change the app registration in Azure, otherwise the change may not have an effect.